# My site logo isn't clickable because of my custom css

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar, elementor

I noticed that my sidebar logo which is supposed to link to my homepage was not working. I looked for the source of the problem and I found it! It's because of the custom css that I put to put my menu vertically...
Here is the code:

```
selector{
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: scale(-1);
}
```

The problematic line is transform: scale (-1). In reality, it is especially the -1 which poses a problem. When I remove it my logo becomes clickable again...
How can I do to solve this problem?
[my side bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjoZY.png):

[image]

Comment: You gave limited information and almost no code and markup. Please [edit] to provide a [mcve]. All I can say for now is to give your logo a higher `z-index`.

Comment: Without enough code, and context, we can't really answer the question; neither [`scale: -1`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lu6w9oxq/) or [`transform: scale(-1)`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lu6w9oxq/1/) reproduces the problem; so clearly something else is going on here.

Comment: `transform` can create a new stacking context though, so this might be a case where a different (transparent) element is now on top of your logo, and "catches" those clicks. Using right click -> inspect element, is usually an easy way to find out if that's the case.